# How to get 5-digit zip codes back in the new version of HERE Api?

Tags: here-api

It appears that over the past few weeks [Here API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html) received an update, which caused all zip codes (`postalCode` property) to return 9-digit values, e.g.:

```
curl "https://autocomplete.search.hereapi.com/v1/autocomplete?limit=5&apiKey={HERE_API_KEY}&in=countryCode:USA&q=1+Infinite+Loop,+Cupertino"
```

returns `95014-2083` for zip code

It's the same for any other address that I check. I have not seen an address that does not have 9 digit zip code yet. Up until a few weeks ago, most of the addresses returned 5-digit values, I'm not sure if there were any 9-digit ones. Is it possible to only return 9 digits where it's required?

Answer (score 1):

The HERE APIs are returning the zip code as per the address standard of the country. Even if you check the the united state postal service site . It is giving the same zip code.Attaching the screenshot for the reference.

https://tools.usps.com/zip-code-lookup.htm?byaddress

[image]